# Unit test private method

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript

In typescript, what is the best way to test a private method. While testing a controller in Angularjs, sometimes controller add a property (function) to $scope, and if I do not make the property public, then assign to the $scope, I may to be able to test it. Is there a recommended way.

```
export class MyCtrl{
    constructor($scope){
        $scope.addProp = (d:string) => {
            this.addProp();
        }
    }

    private addProp(){
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to rearchitect your code so that it is more testable.  You could create an `AddPropProvider` that does the actual work (with implementation details more exposed for testing) and pass it in to the constructor for `MyCtrl`.  That's the classic inversion of control strategy.

Another solution is maybe just make that function public after all?  Private is ideal for hiding implementation details that could change, but maybe you know that function is always going to be there anyways.

Finally there's the hack.  That function really exists on the instances of `MyCtrl` and the compiler only doesn't want you calling it because you said so.

```
var m = new MyCtrl();
(<any>m).addProp();
```

Now if you remove or modify the signature for `addProp` that code will still compile so you've lost type safety.  In most code that would be bad.  But this is unit test code so we're going to learn about the break early and easily so it's not horrible.

Comment: I don't think it is good to promote this solution to the problem. People make things private on purpose. Undermining this by tricking the compiler ignores communication and undermines the writer of the class from being able to remove the private method. It would be better to just remove the private modifier and make it clear that it is no longer private.

Comment: Unit tests aren't set in stone.  They often need to change when the implementation changes.  Avoiding that would be writing functional tests.

Comment: Yes. Rewriting unit tests is pretty common, but you should not resign yourself to this fate. Well written tests should be able to be refactored along with your code without breaking. Depending on named properties by casting to any and referencing a property is something that TypeScript allows developers to discourage as it is brittle and confusing. It see it more as an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to not use the scope as the strong glue to ui and only use it as a container for the controller class instance.this also has other advantages http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E

Then you can simply test your controller as you would test any other JavaScript class and not worry and $scope in your tests.

Comment: I like this solution because it lines up with Angular's best practice of adding model objects, rather than model fields to the controller's scope. The video you posted shows some of the headache caused by binding fields directly.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Jeffery Grajkowski's solutions proposed above, there is one more option you should consider.  Since JavaScript (and, by extension, TypeScript) doesn't have "real" private types, make it public, but private by convention.

That is, have the method name start with an underscore or "unitTest", so anyone who sees it will recognize that it shouldn't be used in production code.